# c# load txt file and split it to X files based on number of lines

Tags: c#, split, conditional-statements

this is the code that i've written so far...
it doesnt do the job except re-write every line on the same file over and over again...

*RecordCntPerFile = 10K

*FileNumberName = 1 (file number one)

*Full File name should be something like this: 1_asci_split

```
string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileNumberName + FileNamePart    + FileExtension;
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(SourceFolder +     "\\" + SourceFileName))
{
for (int i = 0; i <= (RecordCntPerFile - 1); i++)
{
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath))
 {
{ sw.Write(sr.Read() + "\n"); }

  }
 }
 FileNumberName++;
  }
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: So if count=10K then you want to create 10K new,file from existing file? Every file should have how many lines? What if the single file doesn't have 10K lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to split a big file in smaller files with maximum of 10k lines. I see 2 problems on your code:

- You never change the `FullFilePath` variable. So you will always rewrite on the same file
- You always read and write the whole source file to the target file.

I rewrote your code to fit the behavior I said earlier. You just have to modify the strings.

```
int maxRecordsPerFile = 10000;
int currentFile = 1;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("source.txt"))
{
    int currentLineCount = 0;
    List<string> content = new List<string>();
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        content.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        if (++currentLineCount == maxRecordsPerFile || sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("file{0}.txt", currentFile)))
            {
                foreach (var line in content)
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
            content = new List<string>();
            currentFile++;
            currentLineCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can do better than that, as you don't need to create that string and do that foreach loop. I just made this quick example to give you the idea. To improve the performance is up to you